Python Numba is not performing as expected
I have the following code in python3 and I am comparing the Numba JIT compiler performance with a regular code.
My OS is Ubuntu 22.04, pip3 install virtualenv and pip3 install numba numpy
benchmark.py
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore") #https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/4553
import timeit
import numpy as np
from numba import jit

# https://numba.pydata.org/
print("Jit - Just in Time translation from Python to optimized C")
print("\n")

A = list(range(1,5000000,1))
# A = list(range(1,6,1))
# print(A)


# Algorithms to be tested

def makeSquareLoopFor(A):
  result = []
  for i,v in enumerate(A):
    result.append(A[i]**2)
  return result

# print(makeSquareLoopFor(A))    
makeSquareLoopForBenchmark= timeit.timeit("makeSquareLoopFor(A)", globals=globals(), number=1)
print("makeSquareLoopForBenchmark =",makeSquareLoopForBenchmark)

# Numba decorators to translates Python functions to optimized machine code at runtime - JustInTime
@jit(nopython=True)
def makeSquareLoopForJit(A):
  result = []
  for i,v in enumerate(A):
    result.append(A[i]**2)
  return result

# print(makeSquareLoopForJit(A))    
makeSquareLoopForBenchmarkJit = timeit.timeit("makeSquareLoopForJit(A)", globals=globals(), number=1)
print("makeSquareLoopForBenchmarkJit =",makeSquareLoopForBenchmarkJit)
print("\n")
# ==============================================================================

def makeSquareLoopWhile(A):
  result = []
  i=0
  while i < len(A):
    result.append(A[i]**2)
    i += 1
  return result

# print(makeSquareLoopWhile(A))
makeSquareLoopWhileBenchmark = timeit.timeit("makeSquareLoopWhile(A)", globals=globals(), number=1)
print("makeSquareLoopWhileBenchmark =",makeSquareLoopWhileBenchmark)

# Numba decorators to translates Python functions to optimized machine code at runtime - JustInTime
@jit(nopython=True)
def makeSquareLoopWhileJit(A):
  result = []
  i=0
  while i < len(A):
    result.append(A[i]**2)
    i += 1
  return result

# print(makeSquareLoopWhileJit(A))
makeSquareLoopWhileJitBenchmark = timeit.timeit("makeSquareLoopWhileJit(A)", globals=globals(), number=1)
print("makeSquareLoopWhileJitBenchmark =",makeSquareLoopWhileJitBenchmark)
print("\n")
# ==============================================================================

def makeSquareListComprehension(A):
  return [v**2 for v in A]

# print(makeSquareListComprehension(A))
makeSquareListComprehensionBenchmark = timeit.timeit("makeSquareListComprehension(A)", globals=globals(), number=1)
print("makeSquareListComprehensionBenchmark =",makeSquareListComprehensionBenchmark)

# Numba decorators to translates Python functions to optimized machine code at runtime - JustInTime
@jit(nopython=True)
def makeSquareListComprehensionJit(A):
  return [v**2 for v in A]

# print(makeSquareListComprehensionJit(A))
makeSquareListComprehensionJitBenchmark = timeit.timeit("makeSquareListComprehensionJit(A)", globals=globals(), number=1)
print("makeSquareListComprehensionJitBenchmark =",makeSquareListComprehensionJitBenchmark)
print("\n")
# ==============================================================================

def makeSquareMap(A):
  return list(map(lambda v: v**2, A ))

# print(makeSquareMap(A))
makeSquareMapBenchmark = timeit.timeit("makeSquareMap(A)", globals=globals(), number=1)
print("makeSquareMapBenchmark =",makeSquareMapBenchmark)

# Numba decorators to translates Python functions to optimized machine code at runtime - JustInTime
@jit(nopython=True)
def makeSquareMapJit(A):
  return list(map(lambda v: v**2, A ))

# print(makeSquareMapJit(A))
makeSquareMapJitBenchmark = timeit.timeit("makeSquareMapJit(A)", globals=globals(), number=1)
print("makeSquareMapJitBenchmark =",makeSquareMapJitBenchmark)
print("\n")
# ==============================================================================

def makeSquareNumpy(A):
  return np.square(A)

# print(makeSquareNumpy(A))
makeSquareNumpyBenchmark = timeit.timeit("makeSquareNumpy(A)", globals=globals(), number=1)
print("makeSquareNumpyBenchmark =",makeSquareNumpyBenchmark)

# Numba decorators to translates Python functions to optimized machine code at runtime - JustInTime
# @jit(nopython=True)
def makeSquareNumpyJit(A):
  return np.square(A)

# print(makeSquareNumpy(A))
makeSquareNumpyJitBenchmark = timeit.timeit("makeSquareNumpyJit(A)", globals=globals(), number=1)
print("makeSquareNumpyJitBenchmark =",makeSquareNumpyJitBenchmark)

As we can see in the following output the Numba Jit compiler is not performing as expected when compared with no numba code.
Jit - Just in Time translation from Python to optimized C


makeSquareLoopForBenchmark = 1.6181618960108608
makeSquareLoopForBenchmarkJit = 7.653679737006314


makeSquareLoopWhileBenchmark = 2.3787347140023485
makeSquareLoopWhileJitBenchmark = 7.815255765017355


makeSquareListComprehensionBenchmark = 2.4829419960151426
makeSquareListComprehensionJitBenchmark = 8.279022732982412


makeSquareMapBenchmark = 1.5203839530004188
makeSquareMapJitBenchmark = 7.935965497017605


makeSquareNumpyBenchmark = 0.43739607697352767
makeSquareNumpyJitBenchmark = 0.4406902039772831

What am I missing here? Why the numba is less performant than regular python?

Jit = “just in time”, I.e. compilation happens when you call the function. So you should expect the runtime of the first Numba function calls to include compilation overhead….

You can specify the signature of the JIT function so they can be compiled eagerly rather than during the first call in your benchmark. Besides, NUMba is not optimized to operate on lists but on NUMpy arrays and especially to do some NUMerical operations. This is specified in the first pages of the documentation! Please read it. Numba lists are typed while CPython ones are not and both a re incompatible so expensive conversions are needed.

If you need a general-purpose JIT, then PyPy is certainly a better choice over CPython (though it does not support all packages and the compatibility/performance of some is not great yet -- like Numpy IMHO).
